# Retrieve random object in a list which contains multiple lists. Python

Tags: python, list, random

I'm having trouble of finding a way to randomly retrieve a specific object from a list which contains multiple lists. I have tried from random import choice but I didn't manage to get "b" for example, instead I got the whole list with index 0.

Second question, how do I count how many "b" there are in the list l? When I use l.count it always says 0 since it counts how many "b"s there are in the list l and not the lists in the list l, as I understood it.

For example:

```
l = [["f","g","h","j"],["a","b","c","d"]]
```

Comment: Is `list` the programming language you are using?  If not, then please tell us what tool/language for this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

l = [["f","g","h","j"],["a","b","c","d"]]

random_elm = random.choice(
    random.choice(l)
)
```

From `choice` method in the standard library [random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice).